# Number Arrar to String Then Number Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
let c = ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];

let y = c.map( (value) => {return value * 1});

console.log(y); // [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN];
```

**Expected** :-

```
[4654646464, '46546456464', 5465454448527244, 4654646464, 4654646464];
```

Comment: `"4654_6464_64"` is not a number. If you remove `_` then it can be multiplied

Comment: `c.map( (value) => {return parseInt(value.replace(/_/g, ''), 10) });`

Comment: Funnily enough `4654_6464_64` is a valid number in JavaScript now. Just make sure they're not surrounded by quotes.

Comment: ^ Link to the *"Numeric Separators"* proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator

Comment: @adiga, this works only for number literals, not for strings.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, I just added as a reference link to evolutionxbox's comment

Answer (score 3):

The given array of string is not a valid number value so you need to do `replace()` first so that you get rid of the underscore and make it a valid number representation. And, since it is a single line of code in arrow function for `map()`, avoid using `return` and `{}`.

**Using Number()**

```js
let c= ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];

let y = c.map((value) => Number(value.replace(/_/g, '')));

console.log(y);
```

**Using parseInt()**

```js
let c= ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];

let y = c.map((value) => parseInt(value.replace(/_/g, '')), 10);

console.log(y);
```

**Using +**

```js
let c= ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];

let y = c.map((value) => +(value.replace(/_/g, '')));

console.log(y);
```

Comment: be careful with `parseInt` without `radix`

Comment: But Friends the question is that when we convert string in to number then underscore(_) will work as a Numeric Separators then why we need to replace underscore first to covert it into number

Comment: @RajatSrivastava what do you mean by numeric separators. In javascript you cannot represent the number with commas or underscore if you need the data type as numeric

Comment: let num = 5465_4544_4852_7244 and if i console log it console.log(num) it will work fine without any error so why we need to replace _ from above.

Comment: @RajatSrivastava you are not getting the point here., When you do `var num2 = 5465_4544_4852_7244` and print that you get number `5465454448527244` but when you do `var num2 = "5465_4544_4852_7244"` which is string and convert that to number, it will not work. so you need to do the replace. The end result is same, you cannot print number with underscore

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex and join matched results.

```js
let c= ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];

c=c.map(v=>parseInt(v.match(/\d+/g).join('')));

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way...

```js
let c= ["4654_6464_64", "4654_6456_464", "5465_4544_4852_7244", "4654_6464_64", "4654_6464_64"];
c = c.map(i=> +(i.split('_').join('')))
console.log(c)
```